# Unable to use OpenAI Nodejs v4 package

Tags: node.js, openai-api

I've recently migrated the OpenAI Nodejs SDK from v3 to v4, and updated the import statements in my Firebase Cloud Functions but encountered the following error:

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
```

Code:

```
const { onRequest } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
import OpenAI from 'openai'

const openai = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
});
```

Steps are as per described in the migration [docs](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217)

How do I address this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
type='module'
```

to your package json file and use either import only or require only, as it makes good coding standards to maintain consistency

Comment: But Firebase uses the `requires` syntax, while OpenAI uses the `import` syntax. Both are specified in their documentations. How do I use both?

Comment: https://www.slingacademy.com/article/node-js-how-to-use-import-and-require-in-the-same-file/ @koh